# Python dict - how to set a variable as value?

Tags: python

```
l = ['A', 'B', 'C']
d = {}

for i in l:
    d[i] = i


print(d)
{'A': 'A', 'B': 'B', 'C': 'C'}
```

Is it possible to set the value as a variable, like this?

```
{'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: if the variable is defined first, then sure.

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to call your variables after builtin types, such as `list`, `tuple` or `dict`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, as long as the variables exist before creating the dictionary. For example:

```
A, B, C = 10, 20, 30
names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
vars  = [A, B, C]
d = dict(zip(names, vars))

d
=> {'A': 10, 'C': 30, 'B': 20}
```

Of course, the variables will get evaluated... `A`, `B`, `C` are just variable names, in any place you use them they'll get replaced by their values.